# Organic solvent that won’t attack either PET or butyl rubber?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents, plastics, rubber

I am looking for a suitable organic solvent for dissolving dried-on polyurethane adhesive on a substrate of nylon/butyl/polyester.  Acetone is ruled out because it attacks polyester (PET) and Toluene is ruled out because it attacks butyl rubber.  From what I can tell, nylon (PA) seems to resist everything!

It’s been a while since I took organic chemistry.  Does anyone know of an organic solvent that fulfills the following mandatory properties at standard temperature & pressure:

1. It MUST dissolve polyurethane (PU)
2. It must NOT dissolve nylon (PA)
3. It must NOT dissolve polyester (PET)
4. It must NOT dissolve butyl rubber

Comment: How about chloroform?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in the way you imagine.